# JavaFX - Using photoshop graphic files (*.psd) to style controls

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, psd

I wonder what's the best way to use Photoshop images in order to style controls (such as buttons, textfields ...). I first thought about exporting those files as jpg/png images, and then applying them as backgrounds of the controls.

However, I'd have issues firstly with image smoothing, as the image would be resized according to the control's size, and other issues with the borders and other stuff that would overlap the background.

I'm sure there's a better way of doing it.

Looking forward for a response, even if it partially answers my question.

Comment: Would be nice if JavaFX supported something like the 9patch PNGs used by Android.

Comment: @haraldK Sure, I wonder if there's anything similar.